# Selecting elements in using jQuery using an array of id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an array of id's like so:

```
answerIds = ['0', '5', '20']
```

I wish to create a jquery selector like the following:

```
$('.answer-reason[data-choice-id="' + answerId + '"]');
```

where `answerId` are the values in `answerIds`.

In other words, I want it to return the elements:

```
.answer-reason[data-choice-id="0"]
.answer-reason[data-choice-id="5"]
.answer-reason[data-choice-id="20"]
```

How do I do this?

Note I want my end result to be a jQuery object.

In other words I should be able to do this:

```
$output.on('click', function() { ... })`
```

for example

Comment: look into `for` loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var el = [];
$.each(answerIds, function(index, element){ 
  el.push($('.answer-reason[data-choice-id="' + element + '"]'));
});
```

This should do. The variable el will have all the three elements according to your example.

Comment: but is `el` a jQuery array of elements? i.e. can I do `el.on('click', function () {... })` for example

Comment: No. I called the variable 'el' only for clarity. You can have a different name for the variable.

Comment: @YahyaUddin Yes,You can create events with varaible 'el' as in the above case.